# Trying to loop a http request using the Arduino Adafruit CC3000 Webclient

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to retrieve data from a webpage to my Arduino on a looping 5 second interval. I'm building off the Adafruit CC3000 'Webclient' example.

The complete code can be [seen here](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CC3000_Library/blob/master/examples/WebClient/WebClient.ino).

Everything works as expected, the Arduino connects to the network and then makes a single request to the specified website.

Now I'm trying to add the loop, so that the Arduino gets the refreshed data. I don't want to disconnect and then have to reconnect to the wifi network so I tried to loop the following code.

```
void myLoop(uint32_t ip)
{
  // START LOOPING
  int count = 0;
  while(count == 0) {
    
  Adafruit_CC3000_Client www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);
  
    if (www.connected()) {
    www.fastrprint(F("GET "));
    www.fastrprint(WEBPAGE);
    www.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Host: ")); www.fastrprint(WEBSITE); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));    
    return;
  }
    
     /* Read data until either the connection is closed, or the idle timeout is reached. */ 
    //unsigned long lastRead = millis();
    while (www.connected()) {
      while (www.available()) {
        char c = www.read();
        content = c;
        Serial.print(c);
        //lastRead = millis();
      }
      
    }
    www.close();
    
    Serial.println(F("\n\nDisconnecting"));
    cc3000.disconnect();
    
    delay(5000);
    }
}
```

The loop runs perfectly once, but after the first iteration continually outputs "Connection Failed".

It appears that I cannot run the connectTCP function more than once but I cannot understand why

```
Adafruit_CC3000_Client www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);
```

I've also tried removing this from the loop and removing the `www.close();` and `cc3000.disconnect();` but it still fails to leave the connection open.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new using CC3000 and had a same problem with that code before.

you cannot connecting again because you put `cc3000.disconnect();` inside the loop()

so just remove it, but keep the `www.close();` in the loop().

Comment: The [examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CC3000_Library/blob/master/examples/WebClient/WebClient.ino#L154) advises explicitly against this: "_You need to make sure to clean up after yourself or the CC3000 can freak out the next time your try to connect_"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the cc3000 connecting only once or 3-4 http requests (Get) before crashing.

Now i have it working like this:
on the loop():

```
Adafruit_CC3000_Client www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, WEBPORT);
delay(300);  
  if (www.connected()) {
//your http request get
//with a connection close:
    www.fastrprint(F("GET "));
//inser your stuff
    www.fastrprint(F("Connection: close\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.println();

  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    return;
  }


//reading response

  while(www.connected()){
    while (www.available()) {
      char c = www.read();
      Serial.print(c);   
  }
  }

www.stop();
delay(100);
www.close();
delay(200);


and stop&close the client at the end.
```

Hope this helps someone.. took mi so long to have this easy stuff working!